# Django nested query PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-orm

```
class Route(app_core_base_model.AbstractDefaultModel):
code = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    verbose_name=_('code'),
    default=0,
    editable=True)
slug = models.SlugField(
    verbose_name=_('slug'),
    unique=True,
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    editable=True,
    db_index=True)

class Route(app_core_base_model.AbstractDefaultModel):
code = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    verbose_name=_('code'),
    default=0,
    editable=True)
slug = models.SlugField(
    verbose_name=_('slug'),
    unique=True,
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    editable=True,
    db_index=True)

class StopPoint(app_core_base_model.AbstractDefaultModel):
route = models.ForeignKey(
    Route,
    verbose_name=_('route'))
station = models.ForeignKey(
    app_core_models.Station,
    verbose_name=_('station'))
arrival_time = models.TimeField(
    verbose_name=_('arrival time'),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    editable=True)
departure_time = models.TimeField(
    verbose_name=_('departure time'),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    editable=True)

class Station(app_core_base_model.AbstractDefaultModel):
name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name=_('name station'),
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    editable=True)
slug = models.SlugField(
    verbose_name=_('slug'),
    unique=True,
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    editable=True,
    db_index=True)
```

I have 3 models
I can not make a request that will be able to choose all flights that pass through the point of arrival and the point of departure.

How can I find all routes that are passing through and the point of departure to the arrival point?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You need to use the reverse FK relationship. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

```
station1 = Station.objects.get(...)
station2 = Station.objects.get(...)
routes = Route.objects.filter(
    stoppoint_set__station=station1, 
    stoppoint_set__station=station2).distinct()
```

Comment: I achieved what I wanted, this decision is too bad in my opinion
routes = StopPoint.objects.filter(
    Q(station__slug=departure) | Q(station__slug=arrival))
res = set()
for routes_arrival in routes:
    if routes_arrival.station.slug == arrival:
        for routes_departure in routes:
            if routes_departure.station.slug == departure:
                if routes_arrival.route.id == routes_departure.route.id and routes_arrival.order < routes_departure.order:
                    res.add(routes_arrival.route.id)